# Switch view controller without creating new instance

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, navigation

Using three view controllers in my application. I just created navigation using storyboard segues. While using segues navigation to other views creating new instance for view controller. Consider navigation from A->B-C. How to navigate into A or B from C which is already retain in memory?
Note: Here i am not able to use dismissviewcontroller which will remove the instance of C. Such that my navigation should be to already created instance.

Comment: You need to explain what transitions you're using - modal? push?

Comment: show for all connections

Comment: it is not parent child relationship for view controllers. From any one of the view controller we can navigate into other view controller. I cant use navigation controller in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description you should have a custom controller which manages the presented view controller and allows the view controllers to switch between each other - kind of like a custom tab bar controller, but without a visible tab bar...

This custom controller will create the view controllers on demand the first time and then store them as instance variables, so next time they are requested it can reuse them.

In this model you don't have a concept of 'back' as such, you just have the currently presented view controller and some other view controllers that you can switch to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to A you can always use

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];(It will take programming control to root of navigation controller which is A in your case)
```

in case where u want to go to B
`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`(It will simply pop current view controller)